# UV mapping in blender not showing properly when unwrapping

Tags: blender, uv-mapping

I am trying to uv map a cube in blender 2.74, but even though all six faces are placed on the image on the left hand side, only two of them actually show on the cube on the right hand side. I have tried unwrapping in different ways and moving the squares on the left hand side around, but still only two sides show the image.

When I try more complicated shapes (a tree), none of the faces show the texture, no matter how I unwrap.

However, when I export as a .obj file and draw it with opengl, all sides are textured, with the texture coordinates in the places where I uv mapped them to. 
So my problem is that I don't know what it is going to look like until I actually export the file.

How do I get all faces of an object to show textured as I do the mapping?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple solution, duplicate a couple of those light sources(the dashed line outlined black sphere that always appears in the cube startup program), and place them around your object. Also switch between shading options.